# Squid Same IP in two different ACL's?

Tags: server, squid

If we set new acl with name 'ips_with_no_bandwidth_limit' file & it contain list of ips where we would not apply bandwidth limit. So can we write as follows ?

```
acl ips_with_bandwidth_limit_x_bytes src 10.5.1.1-10.5.1.255/32
acl ips_with_no_bandwidth_limit src "/etc/squid/ips_with_no_bandwidth_limit" 
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 1
delay_parameters 1 32000/32000
delay_access 1 allow ips_with_bandwidth_limit_x_bytes
delay_access 1 deny ips_with_no_bandwidth_limit
delay_access 1 deny all
```

Is the above will work? If ips_with_no_bandwidth_limit file contain the some of ips from mentioned ip range?

Thanks